# xcodebuild archive failure: picking the wrong SDK?

Tags: ios, xcode, xcodebuild, fastlane

I'm using fastlane to release an app. The simplified version of xcodebuild command to build the app is this:

```
xcodebuild -workspace App.xcworkspace -scheme App 
           -configuration Release -sdk iphoneos13.6 
           -destination 'generic/platform=iOS' clean archive
```

This fails giving (adding a sample):

```
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/sys/cdefs.h:807:2: error: Unsupported architecture
#error Unsupported architecture
 ^
In file included from /Users/sudeepkumar/Zendrive/mobile-apps/ios/copilot/Pods/glog/src/symbolize.cc:55:
In file included from /Users/sudeepkumar/Zendrive/mobile-apps/ios/copilot/Pods/glog/src/utilities.h:73:
In file included from /Users/sudeepkumar/Zendrive/mobile-apps/ios/copilot/Pods/glog/src/base/mutex.h:141:
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/pthread.h:55:
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/_types.h:27:
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:33:
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/machine/_types.h:34:2: error: architecture not supported
#error architecture not supported
 ^
```

I see that it's picking the MacOSX.sdk, I would expect it to pick iPhoneOS sdk present in Xcode directory. Is this the reason for failure? Or something else?

xcrun output:

```
» xcrun --show-sdk-platform-path
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform

» xcrun --sdk iphoneos --show-sdk-platform-path
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform
```

Comment: What is the Base SDK the project is using ? See build settings and search for SDK

Comment: @puio Base SDK is iOS

Answer (score 1):

Xcode is using the SDK in `/Library/CommandLineTools`. Instead, it should be using those inside Xcode app. Run

```
 xcode-select -r
```

or

```
xcode-select -s "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer"
```

Verify by

```
xcode-select -p
```

Some of them may need `sudo`.

Answer (score 1):

```
xcodebuild -workspace App.xcworkspace -scheme App 
           -configuration Release -sdk iphoneos
           -destination 'generic/platform=iOS' clean archive
```

In the `xcodebuild` [man page](https://www.manpagez.com/man/1/xcodebuild/)

```
-sdk [<sdkfullpath> | <sdkname>]
           Build an Xcode project or workspace against the specified SDK,
           using build tools appropriate for that SDK. The argument may be an
           absolute path to an SDK, or the canonical name of an SDK.
```

1. Use `xcrun --sdk iphoneos --show-sdk-path` to check the SDK path.
2. Check the SDK you have in your Mac. In my Mac, there are `iPhoneOS.sdk` and `iPhoneOS13.7.sdk`

- `iPhoneOS13.7.sdk` is a symbolic link and its origin is `iPhoneOS.sdk` .

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS13.7.sdk
```

---

Besides,

- you can also use `xcodebuild -showsdks` to see all the sdks
- Different parameter for different devices

  - iOS: `-sdk iphoneos`
  - Simulator: `-sdk iphonesimulator`
  - watchOS: `-sdk watchos`
  - macOS: `-sdk macosx`